# Does google maps update current location in offline mode?

Tags: ios, google-maps, location, google-maps-sdk-ios

Is it possible to get the current location (blue dot) of the user if there is no network connection?

In online mode this is accesible with `mapView.myLocation`.

Answer (score 1):

GoogleMaps SDK also uses `CLLocationManager` to get current location info from system, so this is not an issue related to GoogleMaps, but your device, search documentation about CLLocationManager and find the answer.